# How to handle templateUrl for resetting password urls?

Tags: angularjs

When users want to reset a password I send to them an email with a link to reset their password. The link looks like this

`http://localhost:8000/accounts/password/reset/key/9g-31e-snansj0af58ff7301/`

How can I handle urls with different values in templateUrl after `/accounts/password/reset/key/`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always give values something like this in your route:

```
accounts/password/reset/key/:keyValue
```

The keyValue will be available to you using this syntax:

```
$route.current.params.keyValue
```